# Durandal dialog repositioning not working

Tags: javascript, durandal

I've been trying to reposition a Durandal dialog with no success. The code I'm using looks something like this:

```
this.compositionComplete = function (child, parent, context) {
    dialog.getContext().reposition(child);
};
```

This is the compositionComplete() function in my dialog model.

Once called, it doesn't error, it simply does nothing and the dialog does not reposition.

What am I doing wrong? I tried to follow the docs from Durandal here: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Showing-Message-Boxes-And-Modals.html

Comment: It's hard to tell with how little information you gave. Can you provide some more context about what `dialog` is, or if `child` even has a value?

Comment: It's all part of the Durandal framework. The compositionComplete() function is called by the Durandal framework when it creates the dialog. It's kind of like an override method in C#. Durandal calls it as part of the framework's lifecycle.

I'm not sure what the child input is. I tried to follow the instructions in the Durandal documentation here: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Showing-Message-Boxes-And-Modals.html

Comment: @Andrew Only custom dialog contexts have a `compositionComplete` hook. Is your dialog using a custom dialog context? Or did you mean that this hook is on your viewmodel?

Comment: @Brett I'm a little new to Durandal so I'll try my best to answer your question. I believe it is a custom dialog context. It has it's own view and view model.

Answer (score 0):

Dialog.getContext() returns the default context, not *your* custom context.

If you really are using a custom dialog context, try this sample compositionComplete method instead:

```
this.compositionComplete = function (child, parent, context) {

    var dialogModel = dialog.getDialog(this);
    dialogModel.context.reposition(child);

}
```

In this version, you're getting the *dialog model* for your *view model*. It's an object which includes dialog related properties and methods.

On the next line, you're calling "reposition" in your custom context, via the dialog model.